# Shouldn't the [artificial-intelligence] tag be top level?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

It's an arXiv classification. Shouldn't [artificial-intelligence](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence) be made a synonym of [ai.artificial-intelligence](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai.artificial-intelligence)?

Update. Note that ai.artificial-intelligence exceeds the 25 character limit for tags, so I replaced it with [ai.artificial-intel](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai.artificial-intel) and made a synonym from artificial-intelligence to it.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry. Somehow I missed this. You are right - I'll create the necessary synonyms and merges